# Help with a messed up /etc/profile file?

Tags: command-line, bash, .profile

I altered my `/etc/profile` and now its showing off some errors whenever i startup my system saying that there's some end of file or something like that missing and the session wont be configured properly. It also says that this is a critical error which needs to be fixed. Kindly help me out on this.

I would appreciate if someone could give me the contents of their `/etc/profile`

Comment: Mine is http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/12252543/

Answer (score 3):

In the particular case of `/etc/profile`, the `base-files` package places a template file at `/usr/share/base-files/profile`, so you can simply copy that.

First back up your existing file

```
sudo cp /etc/profile{,.old}
```

Then

```
sudo cp /usr/share/base-files/profile /etc/profile
```